# Google sheet: How to allow users to delete rows or columns that contain protected cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a accounting sheet in Google sheet that is shared with other users.

These other users are not clever enough to manage a spreadsheet thus they are not supposed to make changes in formulas or add or delete columns and rows directly.

Nevertheless I need to grant them the possibility to add or delete rows or columns **using specific buttons that triggers ad hoc scripts**. I could manage to write and deploy the scripts that allow them adding rows or columns.

The rows or colums they can add that way, include protected cells (mainly containing formulas) and unprotected cells (where they can enter values).

I want to grant my users, the ability to delete the rows or columns that are added by mean of these buttons only clicking a cell(or anything else) that belongs to the row or column they intend to delete.

How can I do this without being prevented by lack of authorization ?

Comment: From what I understand, you'd like to delete the rows and columns that've been added by the script you made. It would be beneficial if you could show us the code that you have as the basis for what you'd like to do. Also, based on my opinion, it's a bit contradictory if you'd like to `delete the rows or columns` by `only clicking a cell(or anything else)` if the `users are not clever enough to manage a spreadsheet`. I'd rather highlight the rows and columns first, then delete them.

Comment: Thank you for your help. From my point of view the idea is to have a control (button, or anything else) to trigger a script that delete something that way the user doesn't do thing directly and cannot do more than the script does.  Eventually I found a solution providing checkboxes for the deletable lines and using a button that triggers a script that search for the ticked rows and then delete them. That way, the script being a Web App script, the existing protections do not impede the job